# Can I use if_then_else on indexed paths in HITs?

Tags: agda, cubical-agda, higher-inductive-types

I want to define a function out of an indexed higher inductive type, and am running into some problems.

Here is a somewhat contrived minimal example of what I'm doing:

```
{-# OPTIONS --cubical #-}
open import Cubical.Foundations.Prelude
  using(_≡_ ; Type)
open import Data.Bool
  using(Bool ; true ; false ; if_then_else_)

data Test : Type₀ where
  point : Test
  loop : Bool → point ≡ point

foo : Test → Bool
foo point = true
foo (loop x i) = if x then true else true
```

Clearly `foo` is just a very roundabout way of writing `const true`, but Agda protests saying:

```
true != if x then true else true of type Bool
when checking the definition of foo
```

Is there a way to write a function like this, in which the result depends on `x`?

Alternatively, is there a reason it should not be possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do pattern matching on a higher inductive type, the cases for the higher constructors must be *judgmentally* equal to the cases for their faces. `if x then true else true` is not judgmentally equal to `true`, because it is stuck on `x`.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks! Is there a principled way to get around this if I have a proof that `if x then true else true` is always equal to true?

(sadly rewriting does not work with cubical equality yet)

Comment: It depends what exactly you mean. You can use the proof to build `p : true ≡ true`, and then use `p i`. But the `p` you build will probably be essentially `q ∙ sym q` where `q` is your proof, so that `p` is not really different from `refl` (they will be provably equal, but not judgmentally equal, I think). I get the feeling your example might be simplifying out some details that make your real goals less trivial, though. So maybe this sort of thing is what you want.

Comment: I actually managed to unwind my real goal far enough to provide judgemental equality. I was doing a string comparison and needed to use `with str1 ≟ str2` which made the types quite hairy, but it worked out.

Looking for judgemental equality set me on the right path, so I will accept this answer :)

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a way to write a function like this, in which the result depends on x?

```
foo : Test → Bool
foo point = true
foo (loop false i) = true
foo (loop true i) = true
```

The logic is equivalent to your original code but is written in a different way.

> Alternatively, is there a reason it should not be possible?

The term `if x then true else true` is a normal form, and it does not reduce to `true`. In your case in particular, you can simplify your logic in this way:

```
foo : Test → Bool
foo point = true
foo (loop x i) = true
```